# An issue in getting tinymice rich text editor content to Struts action methods

Tags: struts2, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I have integrated tinymice rich text in my project,
When user enters a rich text ( which contains Image and other rich content ), I am passing the content to struts action methods through ajax calls and then sending it to server .

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
```

the above line returns me the content as follows

```
<p>Test tinymice text content</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>with multi line text</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>And <strong>Bold text</strong></p>
```

The same content I am sending it to server .
but the problem is due to some special symbols may be  
at struts side I am not getting the exact data .

In struts I am getting data as follows

```
<p>Test tinymice text content</p>
<p>
```

Facing issue with image as well. When I fetch data from server I am getting valid data but facing issue with `""` characters . example image data looks like below , and it shows an error in jsp as - `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

the error is mainly due to improper `""` characters used . How exactly I should send rich text to struts and the to server? and in DB I am storing it as blob

```
"<p><img src="data:&lt;;base64,&lt;;base64,image/png;base64,
```

Update -

My ajax Code

```
var postTitle = document.getElementById("title").value;
var postDescription = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();

var formdata = "title="+postTitle+"&"+"description="+postDescription;

// call function for handling Ajax part
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",      
      url : "postDetails" ,
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      async: true,
      data : formdata, 
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      datatype: json,
      success: successBlock,
      error: failureBlock
});
```

The form data in above code looks like this when I put an alert

```
 title=test&description=<p>Test tinymice text content</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>with multi line text</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>And Bold text</p>
```

Struts code

```
public class DescriptionAction {

    String title;
    String description;


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

  //Action method
  public String postDescription(){
     //Here my server request goes 

  }

}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more info regarding how you're sending it, anything you're doing to it, etc.

Comment: If you have an error you can post a error stacktrace but it useless without source code.

Comment: @DaveNewton kindly check the code given

Comment: @RomanC I don't get any error, Struts to service call is perfectly works fine . but in struts action itself I won't get data properly as described above.

Comment: @Sadanand Still unable to help: we cannot see what your JavaScript form posting code is doing. So far it looks like it's not properly escaping the form data.

Comment: @DaveNewton Kindly check the updated code - I have posted my ajax code and please let me know specifically what exactly I have to post to give a clear picture. thanks

Comment: Your form data needs to be escaped; I'd try not messing with `processData`. Also, `datatype` should be `dataType` if you're actually expecting JSON data back.

Comment: @DaveNewton Kindly share some examples which uses tinymice editor and can send image and other rich text to struts .

Comment: @Sadanand The first issue isn't related to images; I'd have to look at how precisely TinyMCE handles images.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have written a sample which gives more details. Kindly check and let me know how can I achieve the following stuff . I want to send any rich text to server, image, italic, bold, paragraph, source code with indentation anything whatever is entered through tiny editor. First I need to send from ajax to struts action method then server. please look into the sample and kindly help to fix this issue https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxDQP8DqOYBcSHhHWFhfb1pkRU0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @DaveNewton kindly use the updated code from below link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxDQP8DqOYBcanJ6Z3VNVGt1V00/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @RomanC Can you check ma code given in above comment ?

Comment: @Sadanand If you want someone review the code you can post it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @RomanC Non-working code is **off-topic** at [codereview.se]! Please make sure you recommend correctly by checking the [Help Center's on-topic section](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of a site. Broken code belongs on SO ;)

Comment: @Vogel612 I don't know that code working or not, but I guess OP tries to share some code on the google drive and asking how to improve it by adding some features. It seems this question is off-topic on SO without [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @RomanC Not yet written code (aka. Feature requests) are also **off topic**. As soon as you see "Issue" somewhere a migration to CodeReview usually is the incorrect idea.

Comment: @Vogel612 If you understand my comments correctly, I said this question is off-topic on SO. Sharing some code is better suited to CR because it _is for sharing code from projects you are working on_. Asking about _check ma code_ are even a harm here. I recommended to close this question and post a new question on CR. It's not a migration issue.

Comment: @RomanC sorry, WHAT? The code is broken. OP nowhere mentions a fix or anything alike. This means your comment is totally missing the point, because OP's terrible english made you interpret there would be a need to review the code. Also please keep in mind, that Code-Review is not Code-Proofread. We require OP to present code "working to the best of his knowledge". And that simply isn't given here, whatever wording OP chose.

Comment: @Vogel612 I'm not recommended to *migrate* this question. OP if he/she want to share the project code which is off-topic on SO should make his/her best to present this code project on the appropriate place. SO *is not* the place for vague, incomplete, opinion-based, not programming or without understanding problem area, without attempts to solve a problem, asking for finding something, not reproducible errors questions and other.

Comment: @RomanC so CR is??? Sorry but that's BS. We **review code**. CR is not a platform for sharing code (use github, jsfiddle, ...) and not for anything of the other things you mention. Also my comment was **not** about migration primarily. The core problem is, that OP came to CR, and got killed off, because **you** didn't read the help center. Additionally CR knows these "post on CR instead" as a crutch for custom-flags suggesting migration. That is why I mentioned migration in my previous comments. If you want to discuss this further, feel free to ask on [meta] or ping me in [chat]

Comment: @Vogel612 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268622/when-recommend-an-appropriate-site-for-off-topic-question

Comment: Hi all kindly let me know whats wrong in sharing a sample project? also why down votes for the post ? I am just confused , if question has no details, one can comment, and I edited the question as per comments. but why down vote ? When one should down vote ? infact there is no such question in stackoverflow posted before, I didn't find answer anywhere, so stackoverflow must address such questions. Kindly correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I have found answer for this. Kindly check the answer I have posted below

Comment: @Sadanand Check [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268609/code-changes-behind-links-what-exactly-to-do) about this question of yours for a little more information. Especially "updates" for your code in a google-drive don't win you points. It had been a month since you edited your question when you linked to the latest version of your code...

Answer (score 1):

I have found answer for my question.
I have to use encodeURI before posting data 
updated ajax code

```
//Remove form data
//var formdata = "title="+postTitle+"&"+"description="+postDescription;

// call function for handling Ajax part
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",      
      url : "postDetails" ,
     //Remove contentType , it should not be form urlencoded
     // contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
     // async: true,

     //Use encodeURI to get rid of special characters within richText
      data :{title:postTitle,description:encodeURI(postDescription)}, 
     // cache: false,
     // processData: false,
      datatype: json,
      success: successBlock,
      error: failureBlock
});
```